# C++ exception return type why char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, exception, char

Could someone explain why self-written C++ exception, that inherit from exception return a char * and not a string?

```
class myexception: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
} myex;
```

Source : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: To override `std::exception`'s `what()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since std::exception was designed as a base class for all exceptions, the interface is written in such a way that specializations do not require code that may throw. They may use it, but they do not require it to implement the interface.

If the base exception class required `std::string` for example, then std::out_of_memory could not inherit from it (because constructing a string to pass into the constructor may not work after the runtime has already encountered an out-of-memory condition).

The construction of the class based exclusively on POD types, allows the implementation of std::out_of_memory (and probably other exceptions that get created in extraordinary circumstances) as a specialization.

That doesn't mean that you cannot use std::string (or anything else) in your exceptions. In fact, most exceptions in practice are derived from std::logic_error and std::runtime_error, both of which take in a std::string argument.

**Note**: Unless you really need this, consider inheriting your base exception class from std::runtime_error or std::logic_error. They are higher level and inheriting from std::exception directly is more than most cases require.

Comment: Completely agree with your note. Almost all user exceptions are some form of `runtime_error` (due to external state such as a file or socket not being available) or `logic_error` (the program is logically wrong and must be corrected - e.g. a precondition check has failed).

Answer (score 0):

`myexception` is inherited from `std::exception` class which defines this virtual method http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what:

```
virtual const char* what() const;
```

You cannot change signature of virtual function in derived class. `std::exception` has such signature because  `std::string` constructor can throw exception itself and that will lead to disaster.